Vite server configuration not working with Tauri v2 + Nuxt
I am trying to setup a Tauri 2.0 application with Nuxt that compiles to mobile. They have a configuration guide for Nuxt on their website, however it doesn't work for me. In the guide it says to put this in your Nuxt configuration:
export default defineNuxtConfig({
  // (optional) Enable the Nuxt devtools
  devtools: { enabled: true },
  // Enable SSG
  ssr: false,
  vite: {
    // Better support for Tauri CLI output
    clearScreen: false,
    // Enable environment variables
    // Additional environment variables can be found at
    // https://tauri.app/2/reference/environment-variables/
    envPrefix: ['VITE_', 'TAURI_'],
    server: {
      // Tauri requires a consistent port
      strictPort: true,
      // Enables the development server to be discoverable by other devices for mobile development
      host: '0.0.0.0',
      hmr: {
        // Use websocket for mobile hot reloading
        protocol: 'ws',
        // Make sure it's available on the network
        host: '0.0.0.0',
        // Use a specific port for hmr
        port: 5183,
      },
    },
  },
});

However when opening the project in Visual Studio Code I get an error for:
// Enables the development server to be discoverable by other devices for mobile development
host: '0.0.0.0',

The error is:
Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'host' does not exist in type 'Omit<ServerOptions, "port" | "host">'. ts(2353)
How to recreate:

Create a new Nuxt application:
npx nuxi@latest init <project-name>
cd <project-name>

Init a Tauri application
cargo tauri init

Do the prerequisites for mobile development:
https://beta.tauri.app/start/prerequisites/

Change the files according to the Nuxt configuration guide:
https://beta.tauri.app/start/frontend/nuxt/


